# Database Replication OOD Pattern

Tags: database, design-patterns, replication, oop

Greetings fellow overflowers,

After reading on MSDN about correct strategies on how to perform database replication, and understanding their suggestion on [Master-Subordinate Incremental Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998441.aspx). It left me wondering, what OOD design pattern should I use on this...

The main elements of this strategy are the Acquirer, the Manipulator and the Writer. The first fetches data from the database and passes on to the second which might perform simple transformations to the data, before handling it to the final element, the writer, that writes the desired data on the destination Database.

I  thought about using the Chain of Responsibility pattern, but the Acquirer, Manipulator and Writer don't share a common role among theme, so It makes no sense.

Should these elements be written as separate classes, or methods inside my service? Of course I'll be creating a DB Helper class as well, but that doesn't constitutes a problem.

Wondering what your opinions on this are!
Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 1):

Command Pattern would be fine thinking that those three are different activities.